# How to acces a list from a Class constructor, for use in another class method, in python?

Tags: python, class, constructor

How do I access a list from a class constructor in python, to use in another class method?
For example:

```
Class Data():
    def __init__(self):
        list1 = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

    def __length__():
        length = len(list1)
        print(length)
```

To print the length of the current list.

Comment: As a side note, `__attribute__` style names are reserved for use by python.  having a `__length__(self)` method could cause problems with some future version of python which decides to make `__length__` do something special.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pay attention to the `self` parameter passed to every instance method. It's the instance itself. It's like `this` in C++ or Java, just passed explicitly. And you should use it explicitly (type `import this` if in doubt).

So, as other posters mentioned, you need something like this:

```
class Data():
  def __init__(self):
    self.vowels = ['a', 'e', 'u', 'i', 'o']

  def __len__(self): # if you want to use len() on your object
    return len(self.vowels) # refer to the list defined in constructor
```

Answer (score 2):

You need use self attribue, according python code style ["Always use self for the first argument to instance methods."](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-method-arguments), Try this :

```
class Data():
    def __init__(self):
        self.list1 = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

    def __length__(self):
        length = len(self.list1)
        print(length)
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem, you should use instance attributes:

```
class Data():
    def __init__(self):
        self.list1 = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

    def __length__(self):
        length = len(self.list1)
        print length
```

The idea here is not that you're "accessing the constructor", but you are accessing an attribute of an instance of this class. The class `Data` might have attributes: `list1`, 'list2`,`vowels`,`consonants`, you name it. You will want to set these in the constructor, and then you can change or access them in class methods.

But perhaps you could do even better. Consider these two thoughts:

1. Why do you want to call your method `__length__`? Perhaps something more descriptive (and less abusive of those underscores) would help e.g. `def print_number_of_vowels(self)`.
2. The name `Data` is a pretty vague, considering making it more specific e.g. `AlphabetData`.

Perhaps something more like:

```
class AlphabetData():
    def __init__(self):
        self.vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

    def print_number_of_vowels(self):
        print len(self.vowels)
```

Comment: These are not class attributes, but instance attributes. Big difference. A class attribute belongs to the class itself, while an instance attribute belongs to the instance (and is, potentially, different for each one).